# Angular: error resolve dependency tree, Cannot find correct version of NgxSpinner with Angular 13

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cdk, ngx-spinner

I am trying to add an NgxSpinner to my Angular front end. I am using Angular 13. I am also using bootstrap and ngx-toastr and ran into dependency problems with those. When I try to run ng add ngx-spinner, I get an error that ngx-spinner can't resolve schematics.  I then run npm install @angular/cdk to get the schematics. I then get the following errors:
[image: cdk error]

I have tried looking up the versions that are compatible with each other between cdk and ngx spinner but haven't had any luck.

Here is my package json :
[image: package json]

[image: package json]

I have trying to force the installation using force and that made the errors go away but it doesn't add ngx spinner to my appmodule as an import. When I manually do that I get another error saying it isn't recognized even though it is in my package json.
I have tried deleting the node-modules folder and cleaning the cache then running npm install but that didn't work either.
Any ideas on how I can get ngx-spinner to work on Angular 13?

Answer (score 0):

According to the compatibility matrix on the official [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner)

You have to install **ngx-spinner v13.1.1**.

Try the following:

```
ng add ngx-spinner@13.1.1
```

If the problem persist, try installing the package and do the imports and everything manually

```
npm i ngx-spinner@13.1.1
```

Comment: Thank you Mohamed I will try that tomorrow. I appreciate the help!